# implement responsive tables in to TinyMCE

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, tinymce

Im going to implement  jquery mobile responsive table in to the tinyMCE editor. HOwever when I load the script files in to the iFrame head, it seems jquery-mobile  gives an error. If some one know how to implement that Im open ,
Thanks.

Comment: we are open too, but without code or errors, its difficult to offer assistance.